# Qt resource editor on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qt, resources, qt4

I'm using Qt with Eclipse cdt. But cannot find the resource editor / dialog on eclipse. Could anyone please tell me how to add resource on Qt project using eclipse cdt. I'm using QtSDK 4.8 on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on project -> New -> Other -> Qt -> Qt resource file.
Then double click on the file just created..